# What timezone is the united-states FEC donation deadline measured in?

Tags: united-states, election, congress, campaigning, fec

The United-states FEC deadline for election fund-raising deadlines in 2016 is midnight 10/19/2016.
What timezone is this measured in?
Eastern midnight?
Pacific midnight?
Is it the time zone of the donor, or of the candidate's home state, or the timezone of Washington DC if they are running for Congress?

Comment: Also that is the filing report deadline, which is 15 days after the actual funding deadline.

Answer (score 2):

It is in Eastern Time (EST).

From the [official FEC website](http://www.fec.gov/info/report_dates_2016.shtml):

> **Electronic Filing**
>   Reports filed electronically must be received and validated by the Commission by 11:59 p.m. **Eastern Time** on the filing deadline.

Comment: Saying that it is Eastern Time does not clarify whether it is EST or EDT; presuming that it is the time that the East Coast is using now, it would be EDT, not EST.

Comment: Well, clearly when the clocks on the East Coast say midnight, deadline's up, EST or EDT be damned.